# Ant compile doesn't copy the resources

Tags: java, ant

I created my own build.xml which has:

```
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build"/> 
    <javac destdir="build"> 
        <src path="src"/> 
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="build" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="dist"/>
    <jar destfile="dist/app.jar" basedir="build" />
</target>

<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java classname="webserver.Loader" classpath="build" fork="true" />      
</target>
```

It works great. When I call ant run so it compiles and runs my application, but my application has a package with icons and it isn't moved to a folder "build" so my application ends with an exception that it couldn't locate my icons. When I move them by myself then it works.

I tried to use

```
<copy todir="build/app/icons">
    <fileset dir="src/app/icons"/>
</copy>
```

It works, but I would like to do it without the copy command. Is there any parameter to javac? Or something else?

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sorry, you will need to copy non-java files manually. Resources are technically not "source". The command-line javac will not copy resource files from your source directory to the output directory, neither will ant's javac task.

Comment: It seems that hooking into the eclipse java compiler through ant will auto-copy non java files to the output directory. When I switched over to using javac ant tasks instead, I had to do what Chris Winters suggested.

Comment: Since writing this answer I have changed over to almost exclusively using Maven for java projects. There is a decently steep learning curve vs. Ant, but very much worth it.

Comment: This answer tells you why it cannot be done, my answer below tells you how to do it.

Answer (score 49):

There is no such parameter. You can copy all sorts of files between your directories with:

```
<copy todir="build">
    <fileset dir="src"
             includes="**/*.xml,**/*.properties,**/*.txt,**/*.ico" />
</copy>
```

Comment: more simple: exclude="**/*.java" instead of include

Comment: Just what I wanted! (toying with whether to do includes or exclude java, or dont exclude anything to ship the source with the jar, great for debug.)

Comment: Not exclude but excludes: <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.java"/>

Comment: Actually this solution copies all the structure even if it is empty.

Comment: Comment formatting is removing some stars.  You want <fileset dir="src" excludes="\*\*/\*.java"/>

Answer (score 15):

You can do this using the `fileset` element of the `jar` task instead of manually copying the files. For example:

```
<jar destfile="dist/app.jar" basedir="build">
    <fileset dir="src" includes="app/icons/**" />
</jar>
```

This will copy everything in `src/app/icons/` to the `app/icons` path in your .jar file.

Comment: The other answers tell you why it can't be done. This one tells you how to do it. And it works. This should be upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't.  The copy task is the correct way to copy resources into your build folders.