# How to treat java file as resources in ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant

I am willing to using ant build my java project.

I have some `.java` file in folder `resources`:

```
resources
   --sample1.java
   --sample2.java
   --other resources...
src
  --mycode.java
```

`sample1.java` and `sample2.java` are just resources like `png,jpg`.

Here is my problem: **how can I package them into the output jar package without compile the two files?**

Comment: Please show your build.xml content..  Your question is opposite of what is discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804150/ant-compile-doesnt-copy-the-resources, but worth checking.

Comment: Why? Why would you ship source code with your application?

Answer (score 0):

By default, when a file with java is created, it is compiled to class file(Assuming you are using some IDE.) So, packaging without compiling your java files seems to be not possible. But, you can try something like this..

`<copy todir="your_dir">
  <fileset dir="com/main/src/resources"/>
</copy>`