# How to include the resources folder in a jar file

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea, jar

I have finished a project and I have been testing it by running it through IntelliJ Idea and it was working fine. I created a .jar executable file but when I run it the images I used for the GUI are not being displayed. I did some searching about that problem but I didn't quite understand how I am supposed to include the resources folder (where the images are stored) into the .jar file. I added two images of how the GUI should be displayed and how the .jar file displays it. Can I get some help please?

Thank you in advance!

I access the images like that:

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("", new ImageIcon("src\\resources\\background.png"), JLabel.CENTER);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which build manager do you use? 
Can you show us the project structure?
Are all your images are located in ./src/main/resources directory?

Comment: I use Ant. I have all the images in this path: ./src/resources, I don't use the main in between. Do I have to? The project structure is being displayed in the question above.

Comment: 1. How do you build the jar? 2. Show us how do you access the image file? Make sure you are doing it right: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45580/2000323

Comment: 1) I build the jar using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xo6zSBgdgk
2) I updated mhy question and now it is shown how I access the image file.

Comment: `I updated mhy question and now it is shown how I access the image file` - have you checked the link I referenced? Make sure you are correctly referencing the file resource. It seems you are not doing it right.

Comment: No, I am doing it right, I just needed to move the jar file into the first directory which contains the src\resources directory. Nothing of what all of you helped. Thank you very much for your concern though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. click project -> properties -> Build Path -> Source -> Add Folder and select resources folder.
2. create your JAR!

EDIT: you can make sure your JAR contains folder by inspecting it using 7zip.

Reefer this link as well How do I add a resources folder to my Java project in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using InteliJ please right click on "resources" directory -> mark directory as -> resources root. Then create jar again.

[image: mark directory as resources root]

Comment: I right-click on the resources directory but the only thing that pops up is Excluded. There is no option for Resources Root.

Comment: Ok, so i think answer to your question is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804150/ant-compile-doesnt-copy-the-resources